# No obtengo el resultado que quiero y además quiero saber si se puede optimizar con las mismas funciones

Tags: python

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
def bono (num1):
    if num1>2000:
        bono = 15
    else:
        bono = 20

    bono_total = (bono * num1)/100

    return bono_total


def plus (num1,num2,num3):
    plus_hijos = plusH(num1,num2)
    plus_categoria = plusC (num1,num3)

    if plus_categoria[1] == 20:
        plus_total = plus_categoria[0]
    
    else:
        plus_total = plus_hijos + plus_categoria[0]
    
    return plus_total

def plusH(num1, num2):
    if num2 == False:
        plus_hijo = 0
    else:
    plus_hijo = (5 * num1) / 100

    return plus_hijo


def plusC (num1,num2):

    if num2>=1 and num2<=3:
        plus = (10 * num1)/100
        factor = 10
    
    elif num2>=4 and num2<=6:
        plus = (12 * num1)/100
        factor = 12

    elif num2>=7 and num2<=9:
        plus = (20 * num1)/100
        factor = 20
    
    return (plus,factor)

def main ():
    sueldo_base = int(input("Ingrese el sueldo Base: "))
    hijos = str(input("Tiene hijos (s/n)?: "))
    categoria = int(input("Ingrese categoría (1 - 9): "))

    if hijos == "s":
        hijos = True
    elif hijos == "n":
    hijos = False

    res1 = bono(sueldo_base)
    res2 = plus(sueldo_base,hijos,categoria)


    plus_aplicados = (sueldo_base * res2)/100
    sueldo_total = sueldo_base + plus_aplicados + res1

    res_final = "El sueldo total será de ${:1.2f}".format(sueldo_total)
    print (res_final)
 
main ()
```

En teoría la entrada de `sueldo_base = 1000`, `hijos = s` y `categoria = 2` me debería dar como resultado `$1350.00`, pero me da como resultado `$2700.00`.

Esto, al no ser un error, me dificulta encontrar el problema, me serviría mucho su ayuda.

Y también si encuentran una manera de optimizar el código (que seguro que la hay) usando las mismas funciones (`if`, `elif`, `else`, `input`) y dejando los mismos `def` (o sea sin agregar ninguno y sin cambiar nombres).

Comment: Buen día, sin información de lo que debe hacer cada parte es imposible saber lo que deseas hacer. Por favor aclara por que el resultado debe ser `1350` y no `2700`.

Comment: Hola Pedro, cuando usas **res2 = plus( sueldo_base, hijos, categoria )** te devuelve los plus aplicados, luego usas **plus_aplicados = ( sueldo_base * res2 ) / 100** osea repites la operación, por eso te da el doble, si eliminas **plus_aplicados** y cambias **sueldo_total = sueldo_base + plus_aplicados + res1** por **sueldo_total = sueldo_base + res2 + res1**, te saldrá el resultado correcto.

Comment: Ahhh, ahora tiene sentido... Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te has terminado confundiendo entre porcentajes y valores netos.

Lo cierto es que, al hacer este cálculo:

```
plus_aplicados = (sueldo_base * res2)/100
```

Se entiende que esperas tener en la variable `res2` un porcentaje, pero leyendo el código de la rutina `plus()`, queda *claro* que esta devuelve un valor monetario, y no un porcentaje.

Considero que, en parte, la culpa de esto es que estás usando nombres de variables y de rutinas que hacen que el programa sea realmente **muy difícil de leer**.

Manteniendo los nombres de variables de tu programa, lo que debes hacer es:

```
sueldo_total = sueldo_base + res2 + res1
```

Y te dará el resultado que esperas, pero...

Y si cambias los nombres de las variables. Mira un ejemplo, y reflexiona, para tí qué es más fácil de entender:

Esto:

```
def bono (num1):
    if num1>2000:
        bono = 15
    else:
        bono = 20

    bono_total = (bono * num1)/100

    return bono_total
```

o Esto:

```
def calcularValorBono(sueldoBase):
    if sueldoBase > 2000:
        porcentajeBono = 15
    else:
        porcentajeBono = 20
    return (porcentajeBono * sueldoBase)/100
```

Siempre que escribo código pienso que la computadora puede entender cualquier cosa que yo le de; pero yo volveré en un año, dos o diez, a leer el código que estoy escribiendo para darle mantenimiento y quiero seguir entendiéndolo si tener que dedicar horas a descifrar qué significa una variable o qué hace una rutina.

Te dejo tu mismo programa, pero con nombres de variables y de rutinas que considero que hacen sentido para un humano. De hecho, esta pregunta pudo no haber existido o yo pude haberla respondido en la cuarta parte del tiempo si hubiese tenido mejores identificadores.

```
def calcularValorBono(sueldoBase):
    if sueldoBase > 2000:
        porcentajeBono = 15
    else:
        porcentajeBono = 20
    return (porcentajeBono * sueldoBase)/100

def calcularValorPlus(sueldoBase,tieneHijos,categoria):
    plus_hijos = calcularValorPlusHijos(sueldoBase,tieneHijos)
    plus_categoria = calcularValorPlusCategoria (sueldoBase,categoria)
    if plus_categoria[1] == 20:
        plus_total = plus_categoria[0]
    else:
        plus_total = plus_hijos + plus_categoria[0]
    return plus_total

def calcularValorPlusHijos(sueldoBase, tieneHijos):
    if tieneHijos == False:
        plus_hijo = 0
    else:
        plus_hijo = (5 * sueldoBase) / 100
    return plus_hijo

def calcularValorPlusCategoria (sueldoBase,categoria):
    if categoria>=1 and categoria<=3:
        plus = (10 * sueldoBase)/100
        factor = 10
    elif categoria>=4 and categoria<=6:
        plus = (12 * sueldoBase)/100
        factor = 12
    elif categoria>=7 and categoria<=9:
        plus = (20 * sueldoBase)/100
        factor = 20
    return (plus,factor)

def main ():
    sueldo_base = int(input("Ingrese el sueldo Base: "))
    hijos = str(input("Tiene hijos (s/n)?: "))
    categoria = int(input("Ingrese categoría (1 - 9): "))
    if hijos == "s":
        hijos = True
    elif hijos == "n":
        hijos = False
    valorBono = calcularValorBono(sueldo_base)
    valorPlus = calcularValorPlus(sueldo_base,hijos,categoria)
    sueldo_total = sueldo_base + valorPlus + valorBono
    res_final = "El sueldo total será de ${:1.2f}".format(sueldo_total)
    print (res_final)
 
main ()
```

El código es básicamente el mismo, con un par de correcciones obvias a la indentación.

Espero que notes como tener una variable que se llama `valorPlus` es mejor que una que se llama `res2`, no solo porque no queda duda de que tiene un valor neto y no un porcentaje, sino porque no tienes que escanear el código para darte cuenta que es el *plus* el que tiene almacenado.

De la misma manera, en mi opinión, es mucho más claro tener un método llamado `calcularValorPlusHijos()` que uno llamado `plusH()`.

Ahora, no hablando de optimizar, pero si de mejorar el estilo de programación, además te diría:

```
if hijos == "s":
    hijos = True
elif hijos == "n":
    hijos = False
```

Esta expresión va a dejar un valor inconsistente si el usuario ingresa otra cosa que no sea "s" o "n", por ejemplo, si ingresa "X", la variable `hijos` va a seguir valiendo "X" después de esto y el resultado a partir de allí puede ser catastrófico.

Esto, por un lado es fácil de resolver, asumiendo que si ingresa "s" tiene hijos, y si ingresa cualquier otra cosa, no los tiene, por ejemplo:

```
if hijos == "s":
    hijos = True
else:
    hijos = False
```

Ahora, dos cosas, primero, no soy amigo de utilizar la misma variable con distintos tipos de dato. Aquí pasamos de string a booleano, pero, ¿por qué no usar otra variable? Y finalmente, la expresión `hijos == "s"` ya nos devuelve un valor booleano, que podemos asignar directamente a la variable, así que yo cambiaría todo por:

```
tieneHijos = (hijos == "s")
```

En la misma línea, en la rutina `calcularValorPlusHijos`, me hace *ruido* la comparación del `if`, pues la variable `tieneHijos` ya es booleana, podríamos dejar el código así:

```
def calcularValorPlusHijos(sueldoBase, tieneHijos):
    if tieneHijos:
        plus_hijo = (5 * sueldoBase) / 100
    else:
        plus_hijo = 0
    return plus_hijo
```

También podríamos usar el operador ternario, por ejemplo:

```
def calcularValorPlusHijos(sueldoBase, tieneHijos):
    return (5 if tieneHijos else 0 * sueldoBase) / 100
```

Este, sin embargo, es menos legible, lo dejo solo para referencia.

Finalmente, podrías simplificar la rutina `calcularValorPlusCategoria` siguiendo el principio [no te repitas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas) (DRY por sus siglas en inglés), por ejemplo:

```
def calcularValorPlusCategoria (sueldoBase,categoria):
    if categoria>=1 and categoria<=3:
        factor = 10
    elif categoria>=4 and categoria<=6:
        factor = 12
    elif categoria>=7 and categoria<=9:
        factor = 20
    plus = (factor * sueldoBase)/100
    return (plus,factor)
```

**Advertencia**: no tengo un interprete de python a mano, todo el código lo escribí entre el bloc de notas y el editor de StackOverflow, así que no hay garantía de que funcione al copiar y pegar. Te queda de tarea hacer los ajustes que sean necesarios.

Comment: ¡ *Masterclass* de refactoring! Aunque yo añadiría *typehinting* en las cabeceras de las funciones para facilitar la lectura.

Comment: Definitivamente me mezcle mucho con las variables. Gracias por la ayuda y consejos!